# mySQL max connections with group processing in Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

We have a task being run by celery every 15 minutes, that updates our stock prices in our DB. There are about 8000 stocks, so we use grouping in celery to run them in parallel. Each task handles 100 stocks.

```
    stock_ids = Stock.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
    stock_chunks = [stock_ids[x:x + 100] for x in xrange(0, len(stock_ids), 100)]
    group(celery_get_update_stock_chunk_snap_quotes.s(stock_chunk) for stock_chunk in stock_chunks)()
```

We also use autoscaling, with minimum workers=2, max=10. I've noticed that we are hitting the SQL max connections occasionally. Our SQL instance is set to the default of 150 concurrent.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (1040, 'Too many connections')
```

Why are we hitting the max connections limit when each task is querying 100 stocks? I'm not understanding something about grouping. How can we avoid this issue, simply raise max connections, or lower the stocks per task?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, Your machine has 8 cores. When you start a worker, by default it starts 8 processes to consume tasks.

In Your case, a maximum of 10 workers with each 8 process and 100 stocks would count to 8000.

May be you can look into concurrency and limit it or you can increase database connections or lower number of stocks queried per second.